# Динамик таблицы в эксель

Tags: php, excel

за акцент извините
использую https://github.com/alhimik1986/php-excel-templator пекидж для генерации эксель
все получится только нужно сделать еще такое
хочу динамический создать таблицы с разным именам и информации но не получится через него, может кто то сделал и мне подскажет как ето сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: шаблонизатор создан для заполнения данными по шаблону. Никаких динамических созданий таблиц он не умеет. Да и как можно создать таблицу в экселе, если это и есть таблица.

Comment: Посмотрите что я хочу, например у меня есть список пользователей например 15 пользователя, из них 5 модератор, 5 админ, 5 пользователь, зависит от запроса на ДБ мне дает группу пользователей может дать один группу может сразу все группи, я хочу чтоб создал для них отдельная часть на таблицу

Comment: Ну так выводите в отдельную колонку админ, модератор или пользователь

Comment: Дело в том что я не знаю когда будет дата для админа или для модератора, они всегдя будет разние

Comment: и не нужно этого знать